# What is the absolute fastest way to play audio in Android?

Tags: android, opensl

### By "*fastest*," I mean ***lowest-latency***.

The 2 methods of which I am aware are:

1. use android.media.AudioTrack
2. use OpenSL ES with NDK/C++

Of the two, which is faster?  If there are other alternatives, please enlighten me.

*Further details*:  Assume that my application will be playing sounds that are predisposed to the native hardware's format.  E.G., if the native playback sample rate is 44.1KHz, I will feed it a 44.1K sound.  If instead the native sample rate is 48KHz, I will feed it a 48KHz sound.  No system mixer or re-sampler should be necessary.

Comment: the fasterst is: which is closer to hardware, and that is not the Java, for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked the Android source code, the only two APIs that would use the low-latency path added in Jellybean were `OpenSL ES` and `SoundPool` (and maybe `ToneGenerator` as well, but I guess that's irrelevant here).

If you've got a bunch of static sounds, using a `SoundPool` would be the most convenient option. For real-time generated audio you'll have to use OpenSL ES.

For the list of conditions that need to be met for the low-latency path to be chosen, I refer you to the source code of [libaudioflinger](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp?h=jb_2.5#n2106) and [libwilhelm](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/tree/src/android/AudioPlayer_to_android.cpp?h=jb_2.5#n1370). Short summary: Use the native sample rate, mono or stereo linear PCM, no effects.